# Extracting data from a listview

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, while-loop

I have a list view box which has 5 columns and anything up to 25 rows. I want to export the data from it. The code I have here works great:

```
Dim rtb As New RichTextBox 
rtb.AppendText("Gen, Juv, Adult, Senile, Total" & vbNewLine)

For Each BitofData As ListViewItem In Results.ModelData.Items
    rtb.AppendText(
        BitofData.Text & "," &
        BitofData.SubItems(1).Text & "," &
        BitofData.SubItems(2).Text & "," &
        BitofData.SubItems(3).Text & "," &
        BitofData.SubItems(4).Text & vbNewLine)
Next
rtb.SaveFile(Address, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText)
```

But how would this be written as another form of iteration. For example a for loop or a while loop??

Comment: `SubItems(0)` is the same as `.Text` so you could also loop 0-4 on subitems

Comment: The question is: if it is working why do you want it as for and while loop?

Comment: _Why_ change it if it's working?

Comment: Good question.I'm also guessing that a for each is no more efficient then a for or a while loop..but I want to understand how else I might have tackled the problem. I am trying to use:For x As Integer = 1 To Results.ModelData.Items.Count - 1